# how to set path for streamlit in virtual conda environment

Tags: windows, configuration, virtualenv, conda, streamlit

I have a Conda virtual environment. installed Python, pandas, numpy and streamlit.

I have streamlit working fine (took me a while...).

to run a script that is for sure in my virtual environment and within the streamlit folder I have to type:

'''

```
streamlit run C:\Users\Gebruiker\Anaconda3\envs\test3\Lib\site-packages\streamlit\test\streamtest3.py
```

'''

As you can see the file is within te virt env etc.

Question: is there a way to seth the path in streamlit (from conda) so that running a file, for example, can be done with:

'''

```
streamlit run streamtest3.py
```

'''

Thanks ! greetings Jan

Comment: You should not have to call a python file in the site-packages directory. That's not practical. Your second example `streamlit run <file-name>` should work. If it doesn't can you please share the instructions you followed to install `streamlit` and the error message you are seeing?

Answer (score 2):

this is the error ( other .py file, but within test3 virt env created with conda:

[image]

**SOLUTION:** The problem was me not understanding the documenatation.

How to get a specific file work in streamlit with only the file name:

1: activate your Conda environment.
2: change directory on cmd prompt of your virtual environment to the folder where your streamlit .py is.
3: then type: streamlit run whateverfile.py.

So the solution is not changing the path of something, but bringing the virtual environment to the file.
greetings Jan